# Git lost track of "moved" files all of a sudden

Tags: git

I know that there is no "move" or "rename" in git. However, about a year ago I moved files to another folder (on a branch B from master M), committed that, then renamed the classes in those files, committed. All looked fine. While continuing work on B, when merging updates from M to B, the "old" files were compared to their new versions on B.
Now, all of a sudden, for some files this doesn't work anymore: the "old" files from M are detected as additions to B. The new versions of those files on B still have the entire history on them.
1st question: why is that (I read about the "snap-shot" thingy: is that compared from the split point of B from M, considering all snap-shot from there onward)?
2nd question: is there a way to have the "track" of the two versions of files back/restored?

```
M --x--x--x-----------------------x
     \  \  \ (so far all good)     \ -> ! files "lost" track
  B   x--x--x-----------------------x
```

Comment: See the `--follow` option to `git log` and the `--find-renames` option to `git diff`. Note that `--find-renames` takes a "threshold" number that defaults to "50% similar". Lowering the threshold will find more renames; lower it too far and you'll find all kinds of senseless renames because two or three lines match.